# Rails: Record Exists Rollback when Record doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to rails.  I'm trying to create a User and am getting a ROLLBACK while checking for uniqueness.  I am working specifically in the development database.  I can see the queried user on my index page, so the db's do match.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-01 17:02:17 -0600
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<TOKEN THAT MATCHES THE FORM>", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"First", "last_name"=>"Test", "username"=>"test1", "email"=>"test1@self.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'test1' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'test1@self.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered users/_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 178ms (Views: 56.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

So I check my table to see if it does in fact exist.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+------------+---------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | first_name | last_name     | email            | username   | password_digest    | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------------+---------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Initial    | User          | test0@self.com   | test0      | <SOME LONG DIGEST> | 2015-01-01 03:56:39 | 2015-01-01 03:56:39 |
+----+------------+---------------+------------------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I run the commands as Rails does:

```
mysql> SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username` = BINARY 'test1' LIMIT 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'test1@self.com' LIMIT 1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

It doesn't.  Why is this happening, and is there a good way to see what's actually going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing it is most likely an issue with either:

A) Validations in your models (remove them all and test again) - if it works add them once at a time and you figure out what validation caused the rollback.

Example models/user.rb

```
validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

B) You have missed to add one of the attributes you are trying to save to your parameter list

Example controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :username, :password_digest, :_destroy)
end
```

Give (A) a try - it happened to me on many occasions.

Comment: what's the :_destroy attribute for?

Comment: required to destroy items from the form. Need to be whitelisted.

Comment: I had a wonky validation.  Thank you.  Is there any good way to see that?  I'd think it'd show up in a log somewhere.  
Criteria not met because x, y, z.

Answer (score 0):

You can try commenting your validations (inside your model code) and work with your seeds without validation issues.

But this is not recommended cause you'll be inserting/manipulation data without validation.

Example:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    #has_many :contracts
    #validates_cpf_or_cnpj :cpf_or_cnpj
    #validates_uniqueness_of :cpf_or_cnpj, message: "exists."
    #validates_uniqueness_of :rg, message: "exists."
```